# In Android, Why does my JSONArray have additional brackets?

Tags: android, arrays, json

I'm creating an array that has to be sent to an api. Part of the json has contact info. that must be sent like so:

```
"Dealer" : { 
 "email" : "mjones@fake - domain.com" , 
 "firstName" : "Martin" , 
 "lastName" : "Jones" , 
 "phone" : " 5555554321 " , 
 "company" : "JonesCo Golf" , 
 "street" : "554 Elm Street" , 
 "city" : "Springfield" , 
 "stateProvince" : "Illinois" , 
 "postalCode" : "62701" 

 }
```

My json (when using Log.d) shows like this:

```
"Dealer":
[
    {
        "email":"email@email.com",
        "firstName":"John",
        "lastName":"Doe",
        "phone":"0987654321",
        "company":"test",
        "street":"123 Street",
        "city":"myCity",
        "stateProvince":"Xy",
        "postalCode":"12345"
    }
]
```

instead of being Dealer with 9 objects it returns as Dealer with 1 object that contains 9 objects. Of course, this won't parse correctly when I send it to the API.

I'm pulling my content from a shared preference and loading creating the JSONArray like this:

```
JSONObject dealer = new JSONObject();
        try {
            dealer.put("email", salesPerson.get("emailAddress"));
            dealer.put("firstName", salesPerson.get("firstName"));
            dealer.put("lastName", salesPerson.get("lastName"));
            dealer.put("phone", salesPerson.get("mobilePhone"));
            dealer.put("street", salesPerson.get("mailingAddress1"));
            dealer.put("street2", salesPerson.get("mailingAddress2"));
            dealer.put("city", salesPerson.get("city"));
            dealer.put("stateProvince", salesPerson.get("state"));
            dealer.put("postalCode", salesPerson.get("postalCode"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("dealer", dealer.toString());
        JSONArray dealerJSON = new JSONArray();
        dealerJSON.put(dealer);
        try {
            emailDataObject.put("Dealer", dealerJSON);
        } catch (JSONException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I have a pretty extensive JSONArray to send to the API, and the JSON is being created with no errors. The square brackets are being added everywhere I add the JSONObject to a JSONArray it seems.

how can I prevent the additional square brackets from being added the the json?

Comment: [] denpotes JsonArray so what's error with that ...??

Comment: The `Log.d("dealer", dealer.toString());` cannot produce the output you have shown.

Comment: I understand that, the API that I'm sending this to is expecting it without the "[]"

Comment: The code and the output are consistent. You create a single object with nine fields and you add this object to array. This is the output you have too. If you don't want to have brackets, do not add your object to array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid backers do not add your object to an array, but it to the object directly. Here is an example.

```
    JSONObject dealer = new JSONObject();
    try {
        dealer.put("email", salesPerson.get("emailAddress"));
        dealer.put("firstName", salesPerson.get("firstName"));
        dealer.put("lastName", salesPerson.get("lastName"));
        dealer.put("phone", salesPerson.get("mobilePhone"));
        dealer.put("street", salesPerson.get("mailingAddress1"));
        dealer.put("street2", salesPerson.get("mailingAddress2"));
        dealer.put("city", salesPerson.get("city"));
        dealer.put("stateProvince", salesPerson.get("state"));
        dealer.put("postalCode", salesPerson.get("postalCode"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("dealer", dealer.toString());
    try {
        emailDataObject.put("Dealer", dealer);
    } catch (JSONException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: this is the answer. I'll mark it as such once the time limit is up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really into Android, but I can give you some directives, and I can surely tell you that you are conceptually wrong about your JSONs

```
"Dealer":
    {
    "email":"email@email.com",
    "firstName":"John",
    "lastName":"Doe",
    "phone":"0987654321",
    "company":"test",
    "street":"123 Street",
    "city":"myCity",
    "stateProvince":"Xy",
    "postalCode":"12345"
    }
```

This first example is **not an array** of JSON objects, but instead a single objects with many properties

```
"Dealer":
    [
        {
        "email":"email@email.com",
        "firstName":"John",
        "lastName":"Doe",
        "phone":"0987654321",
        "company":"test",
        "street":"123 Street",
        "city":"myCity",
        "stateProvince":"Xy",
        "postalCode":"12345"
        }
    ]
```

This one instead, is a real JSON array, formed by a single element, which is your previous object.

You have to rethink about the adding of the elements in your JSON object, and what is your real expected behavior

---

**Edit:**
I think that this line could be held responsible for your unwanted array creation:

```
        JSONArray dealerJSON = new JSONArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an array with this code:

```
JSONArray dealerJSON = new JSONArray();
```

So don't so that.

Just do this:

```
emailDataObject.put("Dealer", dealer);
```

You don't need the dealerJSON step, because dealer is the JSONObject you want.